# How to change the resources for zeppelin using linux HDInsight

Tags: linux, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, ambari, apache-zeppelin

I've used the Windows version of HDInsight before, and that has a tab where you can set the number of cores and ram per worker node for Zeppelin.

I followed this tutorial to get Zeppelin working:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-use-zeppelin-notebook/

The Linux version of HDInsight uses Ambari to manage the resources, but I can't seem to find a way to change the settings for Zeppelin.

- Zeppelin is not selectable as a separate service in the list of services on the left. It also seems like it isn't available to be added when I choose 'add service' in actions.
- I tried editing the general spark configs in Ambari by using override, then adding the worker nodes to my new config group and increasing the number of cores and RAM in custom spark-defaults. (Then clicked save and restarted all affected services.)
- I tried editing the spark settings using

  ```
  vi /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  ```

on the headnode, but that wasn't picked up by Ambari.

The performance in Zeppelin seems to stay the same for a query that takes about 1000-1100 seconds every time.

Comment: I haven't seen any configuration tutorial for Zeppelin in HDInsihgt on Linux, the best way to have a better performance is to have a higher tier cluster.

Comment: I'm currently on D12 worker nodes. (4-cores each) The problem is that HDInsight on Linux sets the cores for Spark to 1. I can't find a way to increase this. So, upgrading to a higher tier would only be beneficial if it can reach more Ghz. But the extra cores and RAM would be wasted.

Comment: Isn't just using yarn, might need to just set the the [conf](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.5-incubating/interpreter/spark.html)

Comment: In my zeppelin-env.sh I have this set
      export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dhdp.version={{hdp_version}} -Dspark.executor.memory={{executor_mem}} -Dspark.jars=/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/azure-storage-2.2.0.jar,/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar,/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/hadoop-azure-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar -Dspark.executor.instances=2 -Dspark.executor.cores=1"

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin is not a service so it shouldn't show up in Ambari. If you are committed to managing it that way, you may be able to get this to work
https://github.com/tzolov/zeppelin-ambari-plugin

To edit via ssh you'll need edit the zeppelin-env.sh file. First give yourself edit perms.

```
sudo chmod u+w /usr/hdp/current/incubator-zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh
```

and then edit zeppelin configs using

```
vi /usr/hdp/current/incubator-zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh
```

Here you can configure the ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS variable, adding:

```
-Dspark.executor.memory=1024m -Dspark.executor.cores=16
```

All that being said... any reason you can't just use a Jupyter notebook instead?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. We've tried to add the service to ambari using your link above, but that didn't work because it's only for centos and RHEL, whereas HDInsight runs on Ubuntu. Unfortunately we can't seem to change the Linux OS type to one of the others.
Editing the env.sh doesn't seem to do anything performance wise, even after restarting Zeppelin, or restarting all services in Ambari.